# change the text from a meta tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

need to uppercase the content of a meta tag, the site has over 75 files, and i would really like to do it manually.
Tried used simple_html_dom, but can't find the way to do it....
Any hint?

This is an example of the tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="Aproveche nuestras ofertas y sea el primero en alcanzar nuestro objetivo de promociones !!!!!" />
```

And this is what i've been trying to do, but can't think on how to resolve it:

```
$scraptedText =  file_get_html('../index.html'); 
$change = split('<meta name="description"', $scraptedText);
$change = split(' />',  $change[1]);
$change = $change[0];
$change = strtoupper($change);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function matchToUpper($matches) {
    return str_replace($matches[1], strtoupper($matches[1]), $matches[0]);
}
$scraptedText = preg_replace_callback('%<meta name="description" content="(.*?)" />%', 'matchToUpper', $scraptedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
var meta = $('meta').attr('content');
$('meta').attr('content', meta.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sry, for that counter question:

But why making description uppercased?

Some (big) searchengines can suspend you from their services in case of "shouting". (Or do you have seen one site @ google doing this (uppercased shouting)?
Or did I misunderstood?

Otherwise a helper method can solve your problem
(I worked with the Zend Framework and used their View_Helper: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.8/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers

It's free and can implemented with an include)

Hope this helps